# How to re-sign Silverlight App with new certificate to not require reinstall

Tags: silverlight, digital-certificate

I have a Silverlight 4 trusted OOB app that was signed with a certificate that expired last week. I was unable to release new code on the old certificate.

I applied for a new 5-year certificate and re-signed the app after choosing this new certificate from my certificate store (same Publisher name, company etc.)

Now the auto-updating Silverlight mechanism fails when it tries to update the OOB app to the new version with a Certificate Mismatch error. It obviously does not like the new certificate.

How can I get around this - I would think this is up to the Certificate issuer to "link" my certificates to continue the trust. I don't want to have to get my users to uninstall the software every time my certificate expires and I have to get a new one.

Comment: Hi Rodney, Did you ever find a solutions to this problem?

Comment: No... they had to uninstall and reinstall..

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something better than that but that seems to be the solution to this problem.